# Can't redirect standard input to Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to redirect a file as standard input to my Python script but I get some errors as soon as it tries to collect the input. A simple MWE would be:

A script like this:

```
T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    stack = input()
```

And a command like this in the Window's cmd:

```
script.py > someOut.out < someIn.in
```

And my input file is going to have contents like:

```
[Int]
[String]
[String]
...
```

It gets the number of tests right but as soon as it spots a string, it always throws some exception. For example, for a file like:

```
1
kdjddhs
```

I get `NameError: name 'kdjddhs' is not defined`. At the same time, file:

```
1
+-=
```

throws:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    +-=
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Why is that so? When I start the script through the interpreter, everything works fine. How can I handle input in such a way so that I can redirect standard input through command line as opposed to handling the actual text file through the script itself?

Comment: I did not really understand it, but have you tried to use a string as input datatype and then check if it is a number and if it is you can convert it to an int and say:  in range(T):

Comment: Code working fine here on Linux and Python3. So maybe it's Windows specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong interpreter on the SheBang. I have tested the following code with both python version 2 and 3 (Note the shebang specifies the version):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
print(sys.version)

T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    stack = input()
    print(stack)
```

Now, on python 2 nothing works. Both using the interpreter `python2 ./test.py < data.in` and invoking the file directly results in error:

Data:

```
1
stack-123
```

Output:

```
2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    stack = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'stack' is not defined
```

Using python3 both `python3 ./test.py < data.in` and `./test.py < ./data.in` work as expected. Changing the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python` which does not specify the interpreter, the system's default python is used which in your case is python 2.x and results in error

<strike>I cannot really tell you why python 2 does not work - it seems it tries to evaluate `stack-123` as a variable called "stack" and drops the `-123` part... I will do some research on this and update the answer if I figure it out, but using the correct shebang will solve your problem.</strike>

Update: As @GurgenHovhannisyan says (+1 from me), which I completely forgot, in python2 you have to use `raw_input()` instead to achieve the same behavior. If you want this to work in both versions, define and use the following function:

```
def myInput():
    try:
        # this will fail in python 3
        return raw_input()
    except:
        return input()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Your remark about the shebang led me to the answer - it was using python 2 interpreter instead of python 3 as I have them installed alongside each other :) Solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it doesn't matter through the interpreter or not . The python version here makes sense.
If you work with Python version 2., above mentioned input will work. If you are in Python 3., will not.
Because input() function works in different way depending of Python version

Python version 2:

- `input()` - read input and evaluates
- `raw_input()` - read input as a raw string

Python version 3:

- `input()` - works as raw_input() in 2
- `raw_input()` - there is not this function

So simple change your input to raw_input if you are in Python 2.

Comment: Your function definitions are correct, but you got it switched in your first paragraph.  It will *not* work in Python 2, but it *will* work in Python 3.

Comment: Thing is, I'm not. I'm using Python 3, I've even tried adding explicit python3 shebang but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

This should work the same for Python 2.x and Python 3.x:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys


stdin_reader = None

# python version check determines our choice of input function
try:
    if (sys.version_info > (3, 0)):
        stdin_reader = input
    else:
        stdin_reader = raw_input
# Yes yes, I know - don't catch all exceptions 
# but here we want to quit if anything fails regardless of the error.
except:
    print("Failed to determine Python version")

def echo_stdin():
    """ Reads stdin and prints it back in upper case """
    r = stdin_reader()
    print(r.upper())

echo_stdin()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 echo_stdin.py < data_stdin 
SOME INPUT LALALA
$ python echo_stdin.py < data_stdin 
SOME INPUT LALALA
```